# When you write your own jquery function, what does this mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I came across this piece of code and I was wondering specifically what is going on with `this.each(function(i,e)` and `var $e = $(e);`. I'd like to know what the programmer is trying to do.

Thanks!

```
$.fn.rssfeed = function (url, options, fn) {
    return this.each(function (i, e) {
            var $e = $(e);
            var s = '';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`i` is the index of the currently iterated element of the `.each` loop. `e` is the actual DOM element.

```
var $e = $(e);
```

assigns the `$e` variable the current DOM element wrapped in a jQuery object in order to take advantage of jQuery's normalised DOM methods.

Plugins typically get applied to all elements matching a particular selector, so:

```
$("div").rssfeed(url, options, fn);
```

would lead to the plugin iterating over all div elements within the `.each` loop.

Comment: Additional info: it is a good way to reduce processing cost, instead of instatiating the object again when required.

Comment: sorry it's still a bit unclear. is `$e` now referencing a DOM element?

Comment: No, $e gets assigned the result of wrapping `e` in a jQuery object. `e` is just a plain DOM element.

Comment: what does that mean, to wrap a DOM element in a jquery object?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.rssfeed = function (url, options, fn) {

    //Here this refers to the jquery object
    //i refers to the index in the loop
    //e refers to the dom element os $(e) will give the jquery object corresponding to the dom element
    return this.each(function (i, e) {
            var $e = $(e);
            var s = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

each(function(i, e)) just like

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
   var $e = $(this[i]);
}
```

Actually, e maybe a dom element and $(e) is just user jquery to make it  be a object ($e);